# How can I avoid endfloat placing each figure/table on its own page?

Tags: endfloat

I really like the functionality of `endfloat` but I would like to avoid the behavior of placing each figure and each table on a separate page. In particular, I have some small tables that look ridiculous all by themselves. I could save 5-10 page lengths on my report if I can put as many tables as can fit on a page at the end. Same with figures.

I looked around here and couldn't find an answer in the `endfloat` documentation...

Thanks!

Comment: It would be helpful if you would post a minimal example of a document which can be used to reproduce the problem. That way it is easier for people to help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the package documentation (page 7):

> ## 7  Several floats per page
>
> `\efloatseparator`
>
> Endfloat places
>   `\efloatseparator` after each float in their respective files. By de-
>   fault it is defined to be `\clearpage` forcing one float per page. You
>   may change this by using `\renewcommand` to redefine `\efloatseparator` as
>   you wish. One possibility, suggested by a user, is
>
> `\renewcommand{\efloatseparator}{\mbox{}}`
>
> It makes most sense to place
>   such a redefinition in the configuration file (see section 8).
>
> Do not
>   be mislead by my misleading name for this command. This actually
>   appears after each float including the last one, so is not truly a
>   separator.

Do note that this package is not intended to be used in preparing the final, published version of a document. It is not supposed to make the document user-friendly or readable. It is designed to format the document temporarily into a form which journals want. The journals do not publish articles in this format. Nor should you.

Answer (score 1):

Using `\renewcommand{\efloatseparator}{\newpage}` in the preamble solves the problem.