# list of floats and heads of floats without page break

Tags: floats, endfloat

I am using the `endfloat` package to put my floats at the end of the document. I have a follow-up question to [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/241861/how-can-i-avoid-endfloat-placing-each-figure-table-on-its-own-page) one: how can I have the list of floats and the corresponding heads be compiled without page break?

There is no mention of this possibility in the package documentation.

Comment: You can help us (to help you) by providing the code for a small compilable document that shows your problem called [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that). Just edit your question and add missing code. Then we could test it... otherwise we could just suggest.

Comment: Note, you don't need to create a bunch of images, just a bunch of captions.

Comment: Do you want to suppress the page break before the list or the one after the list.